# Register custom classes for Kryo serialization in Beam Spark runner

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam, kryo

I have seen that Beam Spark runner uses `BeamSparkRunnerRegistrator` for kryo registration. Is there a way to register custom user classes as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do so, but first, may I ask why you want to do this?

Generally speaking, Beam's Spark runner uses Beam coders to serialize user data.

We currently have a bug in which cached `DStream`s are being serialized using Kryo, and if the user classes are not Kryo serializable this fails. [BEAM-2669](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2669). We are currently attempting to solve this issue.

If this is the issue you are facing you can currently workaround this by using Kryo's registrator. Is this the issue you are facing? or do you have a different reason for doing this, please let me know.

In any case, here is how you can provide your own custom `JavaSparkContext` instance to Beam's Spark runner by using `SparkContextOptions`

```java
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.set("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.class.getName());
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "my.custom.KryoRegistrator");

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(..., conf);

SparkContextOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(SparkContextOptions.class);
options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
options.setUsesProvidedSparkContext(true);
options.setProvidedSparkContext(jsc);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
```

For more information see:

[Beam Spark runner documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#using-a-provided-sparkcontext-and-streaminglisteners)

[Example: ProvidedSparkContextTest.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.0.0/runners/spark/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/runners/spark/ProvidedSparkContextTest.java)

Comment: The problem was with memory consumption.

I had some simple POJO classes with couple of java primitive fields.
When I started to use their very simple adhoc String serialization to hand over object between transformations, the memory usage dropped drastically. The kryo was activated in spark-submit. That is why I thought that String was probably very efficiently serialized and my simple classes were not because they were not registered.

Does it mean that spark runner serializes user objects with beam into its internal data structures and then they are serialized by kryo in spark?

Comment: For all user data classes we serialize them into bytes using Beam's coders, from there Spark uses Kryo to serialize the data, however, since the data is already in byte form, Kryo does not serialize it but rather passes the bytes as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `KryoRegistrator` with this custom serializer

```
package Mypackage
class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[A], new CustomASerializer())
}}
```

Then, add configuration entry about it with your registrator's fully-qualified name, e.g. Mypackage.MyRegistrator:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "Mypackage.KryoRegistrator")
```

See documentation: [Data Serialization Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/tuning.html)

Comment: OP is asking about Beam's Spark runner, not Spark itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to register your classes, Kryo serialization will still work, but it will have to store the full class name with each object, which is wasteful.